# Python convert a type 'datetime.timedelta' to 'pandas.tseries.offsets'

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert a `'datetime.timedelta'` object to a `'pandas.tseries.offsets'` in Python?
For instance: `datetime.timedelta(1)` to `to_offset('1D')` ?

The long story: I would like to plot a Pandas DataFrame with OHLC bars, but when there are too many data points, the bars are too thin and the charts becomes un readable. In that case, I would like to compute bars with a longer period so as to get less than 100 bars on my chart.

Given a DataFrame df (data can be anything between second to monthly periodicity)

1. step 1: get dataframe period:

   `source_period = min([t2-t1 for t2, t1 in zip(df.index[1:], df.index[:-1])])`

   (I cannot use df.index.freq here)
2. step 2: estimate target period:

   `target_period = source_period * float(len(df.index))/100`
3. step 3: group-combine data

   `grouped_df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(period_convert(target_period ))).agg(ohlc_combine)`

I miss the `period_convert` function where I do not really know where to start.

For the sake of having a starting point, my ridiculously ugly hack to do so:

```
target_datapoints = 100
source_period = min([t2-t1 for t2, t1 in zip(df.index[1:], df.index[:-1])])
target_period = source_period.total_seconds() * float(len(df.index)) / target_datapoints
target_offset = str(int(target_period)) + 'S'
target_df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(target_offset)).agg(ohlc_combine)
```

**Issues**: ugly, slow, edgy cases not handled...

Comment: What are you doing with this?

Comment: @Jeff I replied in the question

Answer (score 1):

you can just construct it directly

e.g. say source period was `60S` and now target_period is `301S`, just use that.

If you want to change these to 'bigger' time periods, you could do this (requires numpy 1.7), (which returns a string):

```
In [18]: pd.tslib.repr_timedelta64(np.timedelta64(timedelta(seconds=301)).astype('m8[ns]'))
Out[18]: '00:05:01'
```

But that's almost as hard to deal with.

It might be nice to have a function to do this actually.

Comment: that is just another way to express the period right? It cannot be used by `pd.TimeGrouper`. See my dirty workaround in the question.

Comment: I think your solution is just fine